# Derived table where clause optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, optimization, sql-server-2008-r2

SQL server Management Studio 2008 R2

I have a view (fairly lengthy sql code that is a series of derived tables) that is used by several different users running queries and stored procedures on  ~4,000,000 records.  The below query executes in about 10 minutes.

```
Select * from dbo.[vw_name]
```

I am trying to use this same view to pull information for 1 record, but the query still takes ~10 min:

```
Select * from dbo.[vw_name] where ln=1234567890
```

It seems as though the view is processing all 4,000,000 records and then applying my where clause.  I was able to replicate the view into a table-valued function and increase the query time to ~10 seconds on a single record (I'm assuming because I was able to insert the where clause in the first derived table instead of at the very end).  Any thoughts on how to force the optimizer to consider the where clause first when querying the view?

Adding View Query:

```
SELECT      AsOfDate=GETDATE()
        ,A1.*
        ,Onsite_Flag=   CASE 
                        WHEN A1.[columnname]=1 AND A1.[columnname]=0 THEN 1
                        WHEN A1.[columnname]=5 AND A1.[columnname]=0 THEN 1
                        WHEN A1.[columnname] IN (12,31,33,34,35,38,52,54,59) THEN 1
                        ELSE 0 
                        END 
        ,A1.Allowable_Flag
        ,Achieved_Flag= CASE
                        WHEN A1.[columnname]=1 THEN
                            CASE
                            WHEN A1.[columnname] LIKE 'name%' 
                             AND A1.[columnname]>=A1.[columnname] 
                             AND (A1.[columnname] LIKE '%LOL%' OR A1.[columnname]='test') THEN 1
                            WHEN A1.[columnname]='qwerw' AND A1.[columnname]=4 THEN 1
                            WHEN A1.[columnname]='aerr33' AND A1.[columnname]=4 THEN 1
                            WHEN A1.[columnname]='asdf45' AND A1.[columnname] IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                            END
                        ELSE 0
                        END
        ,IM_Flag=   CASE
                    WHEN A1.[columnname] IN(12,38) THEN 1
                    WHEN A1.[columnname]=1 AND A1.[columnname]=24 THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 
                    END
FROM        (SELECT     [columnname]....
                    ,[Name]=LTRIM(RTRIM(V1.A1FNAM)) + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(V1.A1LNAM))
                    ,LocationType= CASE WHEN LH1.[columnname]=2 THEN nLT.[columnname] ELSE LT.[columnname] END
                    ,LocationTypeID=CASE WHEN LH1.[columnname]=2 THEN nLT.[columnname] ELSE LT.[columnname] END
                    ,Location=CASE
                                WHEN DLD1.[columnname] IS NULL THEN DLD1.[columnname] 
                                WHEN LH1.[columnname] IN (2,8) THEN DLD1.[columnname] + ' - ' + DLD2.[columnname]
                                ELSE DLD1.[columnname] 
                                END 
                    ,Allowable_Flag=    CASE
                                        WHEN CU1.[columnname]='1234' THEN 1
                                        WHEN FCM.[columnname]='Y' THEN 0
                                        WHEN MLD.[columnname]='24' THEN 0
                                        WHEN INV.[columnname] LIKE '436573456%' THEN 1
                                        WHEN INV.[columnname] LIKE '4526%' THEN 1
                                        WHEN DSR.[columnname]='1020' THEN 1
                                        ELSE 0
                                        END
                    ,RN=ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY L.LoanNumber ORDER BY (CASE WHEN DM.Departments_ID=24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC,LH1.LocationDate DESC)
        FROM        server_name_3.dbo.[tablename] DSR
        LEFT JOIN ....
        OUTER APPLY SERVER_name_2.dbo.fnc_DT (LH1.[columnname], LH1.[columnname]) DLD1
        OUTER APPLY SERVER_name_2.dbo.fnc_DT (DLD1.[columnname], DLD1.[columnname]) DLD2
        LEFT JOIN   (SELECT  field1, field2,...
                    FROM server_name_3.dbo.SRVDSR DSR
                    LEFT JOIN ...
                    INNER JOIN (SELECT field1, MAX(field2) as field2 FROM SERVERNAME1.dbo.[tablename] WHERE field3=157 GROUP BY field1) CUO ON CUO.field1=R.field1
                    GROUP BY DSR.field1
                    ) CP_Req ON DSR.field1=CP_Req.field1

        ) A1    
WHERE A1.RN=1
```

Comment: See http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3867651/SQL-Server-Indexed-Views.htm

Comment: I am unable to SCHEMABIND the view as it hits multiple databases

Answer (score 0):

(1) Make sure there's an index on the "ln" field. (2) Post the view's query and we'll see it can be optimized - obfuscate fields if you need to for security purposes.

Comment: view sql added above

Answer (score 0):

If that line number you're searching for is from that ROW_NUMBER function then yes, it will have to produce the entire results before it can send you that one record. You might try making the query more deterministic by removing GETDATE and ROW_NUMBER from the view itself and instead include those fields in your query of the view:

```
; WITH DateNow
AS ( 
    SELECT DateNow = GETDATE() 
    )
SELECT d1.DateNow
    , v1.*
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER...
FROM YourView v1
    , DateNow d1
```

That will still have to produce the entire results, but the view itself might be faster. I can give you some general advice, if it helps. A double-wildcard search, '%foo%', is a performance killer, but I know you're often stuck with it. You could look into turning those derived tables into indexed views, or adding your many string comparisons into persisted computed columns. I think the best solution if the data can be somewhat stale is to run this query once at night and insert the results into a single table, a datamart, that will be super fast to query.